# Unity UI buttons not working at all despite having all necessary components

Tags: unity-game-engine, button

I can not hover over nor click on the buttons, googling I am not missing any components needed to make them work nor are there any UI components over the buttons making them unclickable. I am not sure what some possible steps to even fix this problem are. I have the event system, graphic raycaster, and all other interactables turned off during the pause menu but nothing seems to work

[Button 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDS4H.png)
[Button 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXBlE.png)
[Button 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCaTR.png)
[Canvas 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ytjf.png)
[Canvas 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UruSd.png)

Comment: Share screenshots of your button components and the elements in your scene so that people can check what might be wrong

Comment: I just added some images to help sorry i wrote that at 2:30 am five minutes before falling asleep

Comment: Check if this helps ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559419/unity-ui-button-not-reacting-to-clicks-or-hovering?rq=1

Comment: looking at that again none of it is helping in my situation, i have all the things this post brings up yet the buttons still dont work

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Cause**

> Eventsystem in hierarchy got deleted.

---

**Solution**
Add the eventsystem.

> Unity -> Hierarchy -> UI -> Eventsystem.

Unity 2020.3.12f1

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off event system then you turn off all the UI interaction, same with raycaster, the button image needs to be an active raycast target to receive the pulsation

Comment: all buttons have the "raycast target" box checked, and I am unaware of how to turn the event system off, I do have other UI components that work just not the three buttons for a pause menu

Comment: Not shure... but try moving your Event System Object to be on the root level of the hierarchy

Comment: sorry i am still new to this what do you mean the "root level" and how would i do so, if you mean to unparent it from the canvas I just did and that had no effect

Comment: No... on your images Event System is a child of the Canvas component, move it so it has to be the same level as Pizza Section, Green Grapes and so on....

Comment: before posted the last comment i went and unparented it but it didnt work, i also saw that post you reference in the other comment, it is one of the posts I saw before posted this myself, i have the stand alone input module and i also reset the input nothing worked

Comment: Are you shure is not a script problem? make a new script with a public function, inside only add a Debug.Log message, attach that script to a GO, then assign that GO to one of your buttons and check if it works... also you can try to add a new button and test

Comment: I actually did think of this I added a new button with no script attached to it however it also wouldn't highlight

Answer (score 0):

YES!!!!!! I got it it was due to my cursor being in a locked state during game play, I just added  "Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;" to my PauseMenu and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just to help any more people who encounter this annoying issue.

Your `Button` and `Canvas` look all good. If you can make sure your `EventSystem` is properly configured, then there is another cause of the irresponsive UI buttons I think may be the case for most people.

The issue occurs when you add a `camera` by yourself without tagging it as `MainCamera`. If you have no clue of tagging it, then it is very likely to be your cause.

**key point**: The `camera` you use with `standalone input module` must be tagged as `MainCamera`. Otherwise it won't recognise objects with no collider.